# Going for a Ph.D. during a lull in my career

Tags: career-path

After completing a course-only Master's and still haven't been able to reap the benefits from it, I am still stuck in lower-paid contractor positions. I am currently planning on trying to upskill to compete for full-time jobs at dedicated technology companies. If I am interested in doing interesting projects and have some interest in things like AI and distributed systems, should I consider going back for a Ph.D. if I ultimately believe that industry wasn't the fit I thought it would be? What would I do to be successful in getting in and succeeding in it if I haven't been in school for a few years?

Comment: Also, why do you want a PhD? What exactly is your aim here?

Comment: I think the work I am getting in industry is boring and I want to work on things that are more interesting.  The pay is good but not great and I am doing a lot of work that can be done by teenagers. Maybe simply upskilling and finding a better job would be the way to go but what if  still even then I can't get anything outside of contracts and  jobs that are more oriented towards utilizing guest workers?